# How to prevent duplicate entries in my login/register application?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am making a basic login/register Python application, later I plan to add different privileges to users, however I realized there's no way to prevent copycat users from registering with clone info. Here is my register code:

```
def Register():
#connect to database
conn = sqlite3.connect("projectx.db")
        #sqlite3.connect(":memory:") for temp
#create cursor
c = conn.cursor()

firstname = input("What is your first name?:")
lastname = input("What is your last name?:")
email = input("What is your email?:")
print(email)
emailconfirm = input("Confirm your email:")

if (email == emailconfirm):
    username = input("Create Username:")
    password = input("Enter Password:")
    member_info = [
                    (firstname, lastname, email, username, password)
                ]

    c.executemany("INSERT INTO members VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", member_info)
    print("Successfully Registered " + username)
else:
    print("Please review email!!")

    #commit command/save our progress
conn.commit()
#close connection
conn.close()
```

Comment: You could check if the email is already present with something like `SELECT * FROM members WHERE 'email'='<email>'` and count the number of rows returned and if its not 0 you say the user already exists for starters.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way ist to make The columns that you don't want doubled set to unique

> ```
> CREATE TABLE members (
>     contact_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
>     firstname TEXT,
>     lastname TEXT,
>     email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
>     username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
>     password TEXT
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO members(firstname,lastname,email,username,password)
> VALUES ('Johnny','Doe','john.doe@gmail.com', 'jd', 'hashedpassword');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO members(firstname,lastname,email,username,password)
> VALUES ('AMRk','Donnaly','john.doe@gmail.com', 'jd', 'hashedpassword42');
> ```
>
> ```
> UNIQUE constraint failed: members.username
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7f7bd64b4e18c842560d7b0e7600fd6d)*

Also password should **always** be **saved hashed** and never in plain text

also you might want to look into  `CHECK` constraint in sqllite if you beed to exclude complex pattern